# Regex to match TR3456789, ME3456789 or 123456789

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match any of the following values:

- TR3456789
- ME3456789
- 123456789

The rule is: Any string where the first two characters are either "ME", "TR" or 2 numbers, and the last 7 characters are numbers.

```
(\bME\b|\bTR\b|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{7}
```

I can't get my regex to match on all the options. Any regex gurus out there who can help me out?

Comment: Use `^(?:ME|TR|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{7}$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex would be: `(ME|TR|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{7}`

Answer (score 4):

This is my example: `/^(ME|TR|\d{2})\d{7}$/`, and [here](https://regex101.com/r/yO6wI6/2) you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\b` directly after `ME` and `TE`. That requires there to be a word boundary, but your matches are all one word. You can have `\b` on the outsides, but not in the middle.

```
\b(ME|TR|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{7}\b
```